# Checking if checkbox is checked: Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with three columns: id, price and a checkbox. I want to parse the table to JSON but only include rows with a checked checkbox. However, my code throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')` in this line: `if (ele[i].type == 'checkbox' && ele[i].checked == true)`. Where am I going wrong?

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("click");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  tableToJson(table);
})

let table = document.getElementById("myTable");

function tableToJson(table) {
  let data = [];
  const ele = document.querySelectorAll(".myCheckbox");
  // first row needs to be headers
  let headers = [];
  for (i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
    headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi, '');
  }

  // go through cells
  for (i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    if (ele[i].type == 'checkbox' && ele[i].checked == true) {
      let tableRow = table.rows[i];
      let rowData = {};

      for (j = 0; j < tableRow.cells.length; j++) {

        rowData[headers[j]] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;

      }

      data.push(rowData);
    }
  }
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="click">Click</button>
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>12.81</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" checked></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>1.06</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" checked></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>CCC</td>
        <td>1.89</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" checked></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>DDD</td>
        <td>1.94</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" checked></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EEE</td>
        <td>3.61</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" checked></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: for one, you are using the length of the table rows but iterating over `ele`.  Why not use the length of `ele` ?

Comment: There are 6 rows in the table, but only 5 checkboxes (because there's no checkbox in the first row). So when you get to the last iteration of the `for` loop, `ele[i]` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

As you're iterating on `ele.length` you should use `ele[i].type == 'checkbox'`.

Other than that, since you have `5` checkboxes and `6` rows, when you read `tableRow` you need to add a `+ 1` otherwise you'll select the wrong row.

In your current code, if you select the first element (index 0) you get the header row (index 0) while you should take index 1 instead.

```
  let tableRow = table.rows[i+1];
```

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("click");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  tableToJson(table);
})

let table = document.getElementById("myTable");

function tableToJson(table) {
  let data = [];
  const ele = document.querySelectorAll(".myCheckbox");
  // first row needs to be headers
  let headers = [];
  for (i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
    headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi, '');
  }

  // go through cells
  for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
    if (ele[i].type == 'checkbox' && ele[i].checked == true) {
      let tableRow = table.rows[i+1];
      let rowData = {};

      for (j = 0; j < tableRow.cells.length; j++) {
        rowData[headers[j]] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;
      }

      data.push(rowData);
    }
  }
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="click">Click</button>
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>12.81</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" checked></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>1.06</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" checked></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>CCC</td>
        <td>1.89</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" checked></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>DDD</td>
        <td>1.94</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" checked></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EEE</td>
        <td>3.61</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" checked></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

first I do not know where you aré importing your js.
Second javascript Is faster than the dom so by the time you r js gets into `if (ele[i].type == 'checkbox' && ele[i].checked == true)` your dom Is not rendered yet. Thats y it breaks you need to wait for your dom to be rendered.

```
document.addEventLidtener("DOMContentLoaded", e=>{
// Add your code here
});
```